# How to protect data shared between multiple interrupt handler in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, locking, interrupt, spinlock

As I understand that, if there is some data in interrupt handler which is shared with other process, it should be protected using spin lock, also we need to disable the local interrupt. But what if the data is shared between multiple interrupt handler, how can I protect it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is a `critical section` (`CS`) that can be run in `interrupt context`, you use a `spinlock` to protect it, it does not matter if the `CS` is shared between `interrupt handler` and a `process` or between `interrupt handlers`.

The reson why you do not use `semaphore` or `mutex` is obvious, because you can't sleep in `interrupt context`.

Comment: you are correct, I have to use spinlock. But what I really want to know is, whether it really protects the data when data is shared between multiple interrupt handlers ?

Comment: That's why you disable the local interrupts. When an interrupt is being executed, all the interrupts sharing that IRQ line are ignored. And if (hypothetical case) another high priority interrupt handler preempts this interrupt handler while it is holding the spinlock, it will lead to a deadlock. Hence, that never happens.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupt handlers are nonpreemptible and non-reentrant, hence there is no scope of concurrent access to data.

Comment: what about when you share the interrupts using IRQ_SHARE?

Comment: do you mean to say sharing of IRQ lines by specifying SA_SHIRQ ?

Comment: yes, I did. I have seen code where they use some other parameters to identify if it is the right intrrupt handler such as dev name etc

Comment: That would depend on type of nvic I suppose. Interrupts can and will preempt eachother if configured at different priorities.